# How can i separate categorical data from continuous data in a dataset in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset and I need to plot histograms for all the continuous data which i know how to do, however I cant use a loop as there are categorical columns too, meaning histograms wont be created for them which will create an error. Is there a way to separate the continuous data from the categorical data? If worse comes to worst, I can just manually remove the categorical features however I would like to know if theres a way to do this automatically for future reference.

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You can use package "dplyr", and in the example below, you chose all columns with factor variables

```r
data <- data %>% 
    select_if(is.factor)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, will try it out.